# Android Custom View looses dimensions when the fragment is shown the second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-view, onmeasure

I have a custom view that inherits from SurfaceView. This view is mainly drawing-based and it needs to know the width/height of the view. The dimensions are computed during the onMeasure method and it is working fine.

I use this view in a layout that is inflated in a Fragment, during the onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anim, null);
    mPlayerView = (KanjiPlayerView)v.findViewById(R.id.kanjiPlayer);
    return v;
}
```

As this application will run on a phone, I show only one fragment at a time, so I "swap" the fragments by using the FragmentManager in the activity. This thing is also working fine. The problem is this one:
- The first time I show the Fragment containing this custom view, it is working fine
- Then, I show another Fragment.
- Then, I want to show again the Fragment containing the custom view. At this time, onCreateView is called again (see the code below) and it can create the custom view, but this time, the custom view's onMeasure method is not called and thus, the application crashes because the dimensions cannot be retrieved.

Does anyone know why? I think that the layout is not parsed the second time and thus the dimensions of the views are not computed (or maybe I misunderstand something...)

How can I make it work? I don't understand why onMeasure is called only the very first time and not after.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: HI, facing the same problem. When launched a second time, the width of the root view inside the fragment = 0. That means also that nothing is being drawn properly. Did you find a solution (even though the question is 6 years old :D)